# CSS variables: input:focus doesn't set variable

Tags: html, css, css-variables

I have this simple example :

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
:root {
    --textbox-box-shadow: none;
}
.example3 {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: var(--textbox-box-shadow);
}


.example3 input:focus {
    --textbox-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 6px red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="example3">
Enter your name : <input>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make the 'div' glow when the input element inside it is focused.

The code doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

Btw when giving the variable an initial value of 
`inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 6px red;`
instead of "none", the div does glow red.

How can I fix it ?

[Example can be found here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G74MYF1INBAF)

Edit:

Turns out that this actually creates a new local variable by the name "textbox-box-shadow".

```
.example3 input:focus {
    --textbox-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 6px red;
}
```

Still the question stands, how can I make the outer div `<div class="example3">` glow when input is focused with pure CSS and without using javascript (if that's possible)?

Comment: even with CSS variable, a child cannot change a property of its parent. Same as *there is no parent selector*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new CSS pseudo-class `:focus-within` would be your best shot to achieve this.

> The [:focus-within pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) matches elements that either  match :focus themselfves or that have child which match :focus.

```css
:root {
  --textbox-box-shadow: none;
}

.example3 {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: var(--textbox-box-shadow);
}

.example3:focus-within {
  --textbox-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 6px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="example3">
  Enter your name : <input class="ip">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're on the right track. You need to declare your CSS variable as a value, and then pass that variable as a value for different properties. I.e.:

```
:root {
     --textbox-box-shadow: none;
     --textbox-box-shadow-glow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 6px red;
}
.example3 {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: var(--textbox-box-shadow);
}
.example3 input:focus {
    box-shadow: var(--textbox-box-shadow-glow);
}
```

Comment: You misunderstood the question: I want the outer Div (example3) to glow, not the input element itself. Is that possible without using js ?